# Add bookmarks in PDF files using PDFRenderer API

Tags: java, pdfrenderer

I am using PDF Render for reading and updating PDF.
I want to add bookmark in that PDF and update it using same API.
Is it possible to do so with PDF Renderer?
Here is some code snippet to update bookmarks in PDF which is not working

```
File file = new File("C:\\test.pdf");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, channel.size());
PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);
OutlineNode rootNode = new OutlineNode("New Bookmark");

PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);
OutlineNode node = pdffile.getOutline();
OutlineNode node2 = (OutlineNode)node.getNextNode();

node2.add(rootNode);
```

I am using `PDFRenderer-0.9.0.jar` lib for above example.
If any one worked on PDF Renderer, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

[You can add a bookmark using this.](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/BookmarkTest.java.html)
For full code and implementation follow the link.

> you can use follow the link if you want to access the bookmark later.

```
import pdftron.Common.PDFNetException;
import pdftron.PDF.*;
import pdftron.SDF.Obj;
import pdftron.SDF.SDFDoc;


public class BookmarkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PDFNet.initialize();

        // Relative path to the folder containing test files.
        String input_path =  "../../TestFiles/";
        String output_path = "../../TestFiles/Output/";

        // The following example illustrates how to create and edit the outline tree 
        // using high-level Bookmark methods.
        try 
        {
            PDFDoc doc=new PDFDoc((input_path + "numbered.pdf"));
            doc.initSecurityHandler();

            // Lets first create the root bookmark items. 
            Bookmark red = Bookmark.create(doc, "Red");
            Bookmark green = Bookmark.create(doc, "Green");
            Bookmark blue = Bookmark.create(doc, "Blue");

            doc.addRootBookmark(red);
            doc.addRootBookmark(green);
            doc.addRootBookmark(blue);

            // You can also add new root bookmarks using Bookmark.AddNext("...")
            blue.addNext("foo");
            blue.addNext("bar");

            // We can now associate new bookmarks with page destinations:

            // The following example creates an 'explicit' destination (see 
            // section '8.2.1 Destinations' in PDF Reference for more details)
            Destination red_dest = Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPageIterator().next()));
            red.setAction(Action.createGoto(red_dest));

            // Create an explicit destination to the first green page in the document
            green.setAction(Action.createGoto( 
                Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(10))) ));

            // The following example creates a 'named' destination (see 
            // section '8.2.1 Destinations' in PDF Reference for more details)
            // Named destinations have certain advantages over explicit destinations.
            byte[] key={'b','l','u','e','1'};
            Action blue_action = Action.createGoto(key,
                Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(19))) );

            blue.setAction(blue_action);

            // We can now add children Bookmarks
            Bookmark sub_red1 = red.addChild("Red - Page 1");
            sub_red1.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(1)))));
            Bookmark sub_red2 = red.addChild("Red - Page 2");
            sub_red2.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(2)))));
            Bookmark sub_red3 = red.addChild("Red - Page 3");
            sub_red3.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(3)))));
            Bookmark sub_red4 = sub_red3.addChild("Red - Page 4");
            sub_red4.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(4)))));
            Bookmark sub_red5 = sub_red3.addChild("Red - Page 5");
            sub_red5.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(5)))));
            Bookmark sub_red6 = sub_red3.addChild("Red - Page 6");
            sub_red6.setAction(Action.createGoto(Destination.createFit((Page)(doc.getPage(6)))));

            // Example of how to find and delete a bookmark by title text.
            Bookmark foo = doc.getFirstBookmark().find("foo");
            if (foo.isValid()) 
            {
                foo.delete();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Foo is not Valid");
            }

            Bookmark bar = doc.getFirstBookmark().find("bar");
            if (bar.isValid()) 
            {
                bar.delete();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Bar is not Valid");
            }

            // Adding color to Bookmarks. Color and other formatting can help readers 
            // get around more easily in large PDF documents.
            red.setColor(1, 0, 0);
            green.setColor(0, 1, 0);
            green.setFlags(2);          // set bold font
            blue.setColor(0, 0, 1);
            blue.setFlags(3);           // set bold and itallic

            doc.save((output_path + "bookmark.pdf"), 0, null);
            doc.close();            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // The following example illustrates how to traverse the outline tree using 
        // Bookmark navigation methods: Bookmark.GetNext(), Bookmark.GetPrev(), 
        // Bookmark.GetFirstChild () and Bookmark.GetLastChild ().
        try 
        {
            // Open the document that was saved in the previous code sample
            PDFDoc doc=new PDFDoc((output_path + "bookmark.pdf"));
            doc.initSecurityHandler();

            Bookmark root = doc.getFirstBookmark();
            PrintOutlineTree(root);

            doc.close();
            System.out.println("Done.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // The following example illustrates how to create a Bookmark to a page 
        // in a remote document. A remote go-to action is similar to an ordinary 
        // go-to action, but jumps to a destination in another PDF file instead 
        // of the current file. See Section 8.5.3 'Remote Go-To Actions' in PDF 
        // Reference Manual for details.
        try 
        {
            // Open the document that was saved in the previous code sample
            PDFDoc doc=new PDFDoc((output_path + "bookmark.pdf"));
            doc.initSecurityHandler();

            // Create file specification (the file reffered to by the remote bookmark)
            Obj file_spec = doc.createIndirectDict(); 
            file_spec.putName("Type", "Filespec");
            file_spec.putString("F", "bookmark.pdf");
            FileSpec spec=new FileSpec(file_spec);
            Action goto_remote = Action.createGotoRemote(spec, 5, true);

            Bookmark remoteBookmark1 = Bookmark.create(doc, "REMOTE BOOKMARK 1");
            remoteBookmark1.setAction(goto_remote);
            doc.addRootBookmark(remoteBookmark1);

            // Create another remote bootmark, but this time using the low-level SDF/Cos API.
            // Create a remote action
            Bookmark remoteBookmark2 = Bookmark.create(doc, "REMOTE BOOKMARK 2");
            doc.addRootBookmark(remoteBookmark2);

            Obj gotoR = remoteBookmark2.getSDFObj().putDict("A");
            {
                gotoR.putName("S","GoToR"); // Set action type
                gotoR.putBool("NewWindow", true);

                // Set the file specification
                gotoR.put("F", file_spec);

                // jump to the first page. Note that pages are indexed from 0.
                Obj dest =  gotoR.putArray("D"); // Set the destination
                dest.pushBackNumber(9); 
                dest.pushBackName("Fit");
            }

            doc.save((output_path + "bookmark_remote.pdf"), SDFDoc.e_linearized, null);
            doc.close();            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        PDFNet.terminate();
    }

    static void PrintIndent(Bookmark item) throws PDFNetException
    {
        int ident = item.getIndent() - 1;
        for (int i=0; i<ident; ++i) System.out.print( "  ");
    }

    // Prints out the outline tree to the standard output
    static void PrintOutlineTree(Bookmark item) throws PDFNetException
    {
        for (; item.isValid(); item=item.getNext())
        {
            PrintIndent(item);
            System.out.print((item.isOpen() ? "- " : "+ ") + item.getTitle() + " ACTION -> ");

            // Print Action
            Action action = item.getAction();
            if (action.isValid()) 
            {
                if (action.getType() == Action.e_GoTo) 
                {
                    Destination dest = action.getDest();
                    if (dest.isValid()) 
                    {
                        Page page = dest.getPage();
                        System.out.println("GoTo Page #" + page.getIndex());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Not a 'GoTo' action");
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("NULL");
            }

            if (item.hasChildren())  // Recursively print children sub-trees
            {
                PrintOutlineTree(item.getFirstChild());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine. But I want to use only `com.sun.pdfview` package. Which is there in PDFRenderer API

Comment: ok i will try my best to work on sun.pdfview.. i will post an answer if i get it.@Navnath

Comment: Have you got any way for this?

Comment: I will help you asap .Sorry no luck now :(

Comment: It's ok Deepanshu. If I found, I'll share it over here. But it will really helpful for me if you could share your inputs.